# PSTricks 3D drawing -- tweaking of parameters

Tags: pstricks, pst-solides3d

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-solides3d}

\begin{document}

\psset{viewpoint = 15 -30 11, Decran = 10}
\begin{pspicture}[solidmemory](-8.25,-1)(5.3,2.05)
  \psSolid[object = point, args = 15.5 3 7.3, name = L]
  \psSolid[object = point, args = -55 2 3.5,  name = R]
  \psSolid[object = line, linecolor = red!50, linestyle = dashed, linewidth = 2pt, args = R L]
  \psSolid[object = parallelepiped, a = 6.0, b = 6.0, c = 6.5, RotZ = -15, fillcolor = blue!50, name = parallelepipedum, action = draw*](0 0 1.5)
  \multido{\iA = 0+1}{8}{%
    \psSolid[object = point, linecolor = black, definition = solidgetsommet, args = parallelepipedum \iA, name = C\iA]
   \psset{object = line, linecolor = darkgray!50, linestyle = dotted}
    \psSolid[args = L C\iA]
    \psSolid[args = R C\iA]
  }
  \psSolid[object = parallelepiped, a = 6.0, b = 6.0, c = 6.5, RotZ = -15, name = parallelipipidum, action = draw](0 0 1.5)
  \multido{\iB = 0+1}{4}{%
    \psSolid[object = point, definition = solidgetsommet, args = parallelipipidum \iB, name = Top\iB, action = none]
  }
  \psSolid[object = line, args = Top0 Top2]
  \psSolid[object = line, args = Top1 Top3]
  \psSolid[object = point, definition = solidcentreface, args = parallelipipidum 0]
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Can someone help me tweak the parameters to get each pair of the dashed, gray lines to lie perfectly on top of each other.

I've tried a long time but I'm in the dark. `:(`

I should point out that the parameters in question are `args = 15.5 3 7.3`, `args = -55 2 3.5`, and `a = 6.0, b = 6.0, c = 6.5, RotZ = -15`. (The values of `a`, `b`, `c`, and `RotZ` should be the same for the two objects.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The vanishing points for lines that are parallel to the ground lie at eye level, so the `z` position of the `point` objects needs to be equal to the `z` value of the `viewpoint`.
2. The vanishing points for lines pointing in a horizontal angle `theta` lie at `x=tan(theta)*yv + xv`, where `yv` and `xv` are the `x` and `y` components of the `viewpoint`.
3. The vanishing points lie on the horizon line, which is at `y=0`.

So, for a viewpoint of `15 -30 11` and a rotation of the cuboid of `-15 degrees`, the vanishing points lie at `23.04 0 11` and `-96.96 0 11`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-solides3d}

\begin{document}

\psset{viewpoint = 15 -30 11, Decran = 6}
\begin{pspicture}[solidmemory](-8.25,-1)(5.3,2.05)
  \psSolid[object = point, args = 23.04 0 11, name = L]
  \psSolid[object = point, args = -96.96 0 11,  name = R]
  \psSolid[object = line, linecolor = red!50, linestyle = dashed, linewidth = 2pt, args = R L]
  \psSolid[object = parallelepiped, a = 8.0, b = 8.0, c = 8.5, RotZ = -15, fillcolor = blue!50, name = parallelepipedum, action = draw*](0 0 1.5)
  \multido{\iA = 0+1}{8}{%
    \psSolid[object = point, linecolor = black, definition = solidgetsommet, args = parallelepipedum \iA, name = C\iA]
   \psset{object = line, linecolor = darkgray!50, linestyle = dotted}
    \psSolid[args = L C\iA]
    \psSolid[args = R C\iA]
  }
  \psSolid[object = parallelepiped, a = 8.0, b = 8.0, c = 8.5, RotZ = -15, name = parallelipipidum, action = draw](0 0 1.5)
  \multido{\iB = 0+1}{4}{%
    \psSolid[object = point, definition = solidgetsommet, args = parallelipipidum \iB, name = Top\iB, action = none]
  }
  \psSolid[object = line, args = Top0 Top2]
  \psSolid[object = line, args = Top1 Top3]
  \psSolid[object = point, definition = solidcentreface, args = parallelipipidum 0]
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```