# LuaPSTricks error when compiling

Tags: luatex, compilation-error, luapstricks

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-solides3d}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/203609/15874
\centering
 \psset{
   unit = 1.1,
   viewpoint = 10 45 8 rtp2xyz,
   Decran = 5
 }
  \begin{pspicture}[solidmemory](-3.87,-0.34)(6.78,2.8)
    \psSolid[
      object = point,
      args = 6 -0.1 1.4,
      name = L
    ]
    \psSolid[
      object = point,
      args = -12 9.7 1.4,
      name = R
    ]
    \psSolid[
      object = line,
      linecolor = red!50,
      linestyle = dashed,
      linewidth = 2pt,
      args = R L
    ]
    \psSolid[
      object = parallelepiped,
      a = 4.56,
      b = 4.56,
      c = 3.9,
      RotZ = -8,
      fillcolor = blue!50,
      name = parallelepipedum,
      action = draw*
    ](0 0 2)
    \multido
      {\iA = 0+1}
      {8}
      {\psSolid[
         object = point,
         linecolor = black,
         definition = solidgetsommet,
         args = parallelepipedum \iA,
         name = C\iA
       ]
      \psset{
        object = line,
        linecolor = darkgray!50,
        linestyle = dotted
      }
       \psSolid[
         args = L C\iA
       ]
       \psSolid[
         args = R C\iA
       ]
    \psSolid[
      object = parallelepiped,
      a = 4.56,
      b = 4.56,
      c = 3.9,
      RotZ = -8,
      name = parallelipipidum,
      action = draw
    ](0 0 2)
   }
  \end{pspicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

When I compile using LuaLaTeX, I get the following error:

```
..2022/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/luapstricks/luapstricks.lua:801: Unknown name "c
harpath"
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'error'
    ...2022/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/luapstricks/luapstricks.lua:4089: in function 
<...2022/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/luapstricks/luapstricks.lua:4066>
    (...tail calls...)
    [C]: in function 'vf.node'
    ...2022/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/luapstricks/luapstricks.lua:4131: in function 
<...2022/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/luapstricks/luapstricks.lua:4122>.
<argument> ...not:N \tex_shipout:D \box_use:N \l_shipout_box 
                                                  \__shipout_drop_firstpage_...
```

How do I fix this?

I think it is do to an error in [`luapstricks`](https://ctan.org/pkg/luapstricks).

Comment: https://github.com/zauguin/luapstricks/issues/82

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Hi Ulrike. Thanks for pointing me to the issue logged at Github. Unfortunately, I cannot figure out what the fix is (if there is any). Can you please elaborate? `:-)`

Comment: open issues are open. Ask in the tracker if there are news or what to do.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I missed that the issue was open. Sorry.